# stop setTime from another function with local variable

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, local-variables, clearinterval

thanks for helping!
The main goal of this is Stop the timer. But It does not work.
I know that this does not work because I am calling a local variable from another function but If I declare the variable as global the setTime starts automatically and It is not what I want.
How could a solve it, or another alternative? thanks!!
This is my code:

```js
var interval2;

function startTimef(){

    var startTime = Date.now();
    interval2 = setInterval(function() {
    var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime - 5000;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);
    
}, 75);

}

function myStopFunction(interval2) {
    
    clearInterval(interval2); // does not work because interval2 is a local variable in StartTime.
    
 var result = document.getElementById("result");
    var score = document.getElementById("timer").textContent;

  if (score < -0.200) { result.innerHTML = score+" Almost there ";}
    if (score < -500 && score < -0.200) { result.innerHTML = "Almost there";}
    if (score > -0.200 && score < 0 ) { result.innerHTML = "No too bad mate";}
    if (score > -0.100 && score < 0.200 ) { result.innerHTML = "Perfect !!!";}
    if (score > 0.200 ) { result.innerHTML = "You need some work!";}
   
};

// Press Enter Keyboard
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TimeOver</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-box">
    <h2>Try to Stop the timer as close as possible to cero</h2>
    <p id="timer">0000</p>
    <button id="stop" onclick="myStopFunction()" >Stop time</button>
    <span id="result"></span>
    <button id="" onclick="startTimef()" >start</button>  
</div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Removing `interval2` from `myStopFunction(interval2)` will work.
Your first approach will not since you have 2 `interval2` variables and JS will use the locally declared `interval2` instead of the outer `interval2`.

```js
var interval2;

function startTimef(){

    var startTime = Date.now();
    interval2 = setInterval(function() {
        var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime - 5000;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);

    }, 75);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(interval2);
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  var score = document.getElementById("timer").textContent;

  if (score < -0.200) { result.innerHTML = score+" Almost there ";}
    if (score < -500 && score < -0.200) { result.innerHTML = "Almost there";}
    if (score > -0.200 && score < 0 ) { result.innerHTML = "No too bad mate";}
    if (score > -0.100 && score < 0.200 ) { result.innerHTML = "Perfect !!!";}
    if (score > 0.200 ) { result.innerHTML = "You need some work!";}
   
};

// Press Enter Keyboard
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TimeOver</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-box">
    <h2>Try to Stop the timer as close as possible to cero</h2>
    <p id="timer">0000</p>
    <button id="stop" onclick="myStopFunction()" >Stop time</button>
    <span id="result"></span>
    <button id="" onclick="startTimef()" >start</button>  
</div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```